# html onchange event not being called from ajax generated dropdown list

Tags: javascript, java, html, ajax

I have an ajax generated dropdown list.  When the list generates it sends it back to the HTML like below.
However, the HTML side onchange() event does not seem to kick in.  How can I get this to work?

```
function listSess(){
 var name = document.getElementById("studentID").value;

 $.ajax({
    url : "<%=context%>/ListSessionsServlet?name=" + name,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    dataType: "json",
      success : function(data) {
          var toAppend = '';
          $.each(data,function(i,o){

              toAppend += '<option>'+o.sessid+'</option>';
             });

        $('#sessid')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append(toAppend);

      }  
});
} 


<select id="sessid" name="sessid" onchange="listStudents();">  <--onchange not working when getting ajax generated list
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you bind the change event using jQuery instead of inline as a tag attribute, you can trigger it with jQuery in your AJAX callback:

```
// Hook up the change event on DOM ready
$(function() {
    $('#sessid').change(function() {
        listStudents();
    });
});

function listSess(){
 var name = document.getElementById("studentID").value;

 $.ajax({
    url : "<%=context%>/ListSessionsServlet?name=" + name,
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    dataType: "json",
      success : function(data) {
          var toAppend = '';
          $.each(data,function(i,o){
              toAppend += '<option>'+o.sessid+'</option>';
             });

        $('#sessid')
            .find('option')
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append(toAppend);

        $('#sessid').change(); // fire change
      }  
});
} 

<select id="sessid" name="sessid"></select>
```

Your current logic for building out the new `<options>` might not work without them having a `value` attribute. Here's how I might change it:

```
...
success : function(data) {
    var $sessid = $('#sessid');
    $sessid.find('option').remove();
    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        $sessid.append($('<option />').val(item.sessid).text(item.sessid));
    });
    $sessid.val(data[0].sessid).change();
}  
...
```

Comment: so I wouldn't have to re-write listStudent(), correct?  That above code you have would just access it?

Comment: The value selected on the dropdown list shows up, when I select it, it disappears.  Should I move .remove() to another section of the code?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is. Your `<option>` elements aren't given a `value` attribute. I'm editing to show an alternative to building the new options.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the changes.  It's just that when I select the dropdown list, I see the values, but when I click on it, it disappears. The value seems to disappear off the list.